# Why my website is crawled and indexed but doesn’t appear on serp at all?

Tags: google-search, search-results, google-index

I’m working on a project which started almost 2 months ago. When I check GSC (Google Search Console) everything looks good, url is on Google, and when i search my site this way: “site:mysite.com”, i see all the pages that i want. But when i search a keyword, i’m not even the last result. Not appearing on serp at all. I need to say that i have seo optimized content across the website at least 1500 words per page including relevant videos and images and internal linking.

So, if my site is crawled, indexed, and appears when i search it using it’s url, why it is not appearing on serp? At least as the very very last result?

Comment: There are so many sites on the internet that google has to be *very* selective with what it shows in SERPs. The #1 reason I see for sites not showing up in serps is because they don't have enough relevant and high-quality backlinks, which signal trust to google. The linked post goes into a lot more detail on that. Good luck!

Comment: There is a core update in process over the next two weeks. https://searchengineland.com/google-releases-may-2022-broad-core-update-385435